# Creating a small, barebones, liveCD

Tags: live-usb, live-cd, custom-distributions

So before I start off I just want to say that I have searched high and low for this and a lot of the customization software I have found either doesn't work or is no longer being developed.

So what I am trying to do is create a custom live CD distro, that on boot up only shows a browser (i.e google chrome). It doesn't need a desktop environment because the software will be used to connect to my virtual machines.

What the issue I am having is that whenever I try and create a Iso using the ubuntu customization kit, using ubuntu mini remix, I can't through the gui because it is a alternate version of ubuntu. But even when I try and create it through the remaster script I can't mount it because it constantly gives me the "error 32" claiming that it can't find it even when I am in the directory where that file sits.

As a side note, I am not a full fledged linux user, but I can research to figure out most of the things I need to do with this. I am just hitting a huge roadblock when it comes to getting a remastering software to work.

If anyone has any suggestions on any other type of remastering software to use or even a different base .iso to use I am open for suggestions.

Just to label the things in a neat manner as to what I am looking for:

1. A light weight live CD that will work on low spec machines
2. On boot it goes straight to a browser(I know of auto start scripts so this shouldn't be too hard for me to figure out)
3. Almost no software on it
4. Something that doesn't prompt me on startup for different install options(this is for remote agents to just pop in the CD and go)

Thank you all for taking a look at this and I appreciate your time.

Comment: i know, this might won't belong here... But do you need to use Ubuntu? Or could you also use a diffrent distro?

Comment: @frog I absolutely can use a different distro. Ubuntu is just the one I have the most experience with and here seemed like the best place to get answers.